# Problems with price calculation over a date range

Tags: javascript

Am having an issue with charges not being calculated correctly on a charges system.

Below is the code which if you run across a date range rather than giving 2 days at 1 price and then say 1 day for another price it doesnt. Below is a sample of the code:

```
$(function () {
    function change_charges() {
        var checkin_mon = Number($("#checkindate_Month_ID").val());
        var checkin_day = Number($("#checkindate_Day_ID").val());
        var checkin_year = Number($("#checkindate_Year_ID").val());
        var checkout_mon = Number($("#checkoutdate_Month_ID").val());
        var checkout_day = Number($("#checkoutdate_Day_ID").val());
        var checkout_year = Number($("#checkoutdate_Year_ID").val());
        var checkin_date = new Date();
        checkin_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, checkin_mon, checkin_day);
        var checkout_date = new Date();
        checkout_date.setFullYear(checkout_year, checkout_mon, checkout_day);
        var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        //Calculate difference btw the two dates, and convert to days
        var stay = Math.ceil((checkout_date.getTime() - checkin_date.getTime()) / (one_day));
        var room_type = $("#room_type").val();
        var charges = 0;
        var n_charges = 0;
        var st_date = new Date();
        var end_date = new Date();
        var mon_stay = 0;
        var rem_stay = 0;
        if (room_type == "Villa") {
            st_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 4, 1);
            end_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 9, 31);
            if (checkin_date >= st_date && checkin_date <= end_date) {
                charges = 1995;
                n_charges = 2995;
                if (checkout_date > end_date) mon_stay = Math.ceil((end_date.getTime() - checkin_date.getTime()) / (one_day));
            }
            st_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 10, 1);
            end_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 11, 15);
            if (checkin_date >= st_date && checkin_date <= end_date) {
                charges = 2995;
                n_charges = 2995;
                if (checkout_date > end_date) mon_stay = Math.ceil((end_date.getTime() - checkin_date.getTime()) / (one_day));
            }
            st_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 11, 16);
            end_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 11, 31);
            if (checkin_date >= st_date && checkin_date <= end_date) {
                charges = 5900;
                n_charges = 5900;
                if (checkout_date > end_date) mon_stay = Math.ceil((end_date.getTime() - checkin_date.getTime()) / (one_day));
            }
            st_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 0, 1);
            end_date.setFullYear(checkin_year, 0, 15);
            if (checkin_date >= st_date && checkin_date <= end_date) {
                charges = 5900;
                n_charges = 3900;
                if (checkout_date > end_date) mon_stay = Math.ceil((end_date.getTime() - checkin_date.getTime()) / (one_day));
            }
            st_date.setFullYear(2013, 0, 16);
            end_date.setFullYear(2013, 3, 30);
            if (checkin_date >= st_date && checkin_date <= end_date) {
                charges = 3900;
                n_charges = 2223;
                if (checkout_date > end_date) mon_stay = Math.ceil((end_date.getTime() - checkin_date.getTime()) / (one_day));
            }
```

if(stay > 1){

```
   if(mon_stay == 0)mon_stay = 1;

   if(mon_stay != 0){
      rem_stay = stay - mon_stay;

      charges = (mon_stay*charges) + (rem_stay*n_charges);   

   }

   else
   charges*=stay;
```

}

var today = new Date();

if(checkin_date < today || checkout_date < today || checkout_date < checkin_date){

```
    charges = 0;


}
```

$("#tot_charges").html(charges.toFixed(2));

}

$("#checkindate_Month_ID").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

$("#checkindate_Day_ID").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

$("#checkindate_Year_ID").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

$("#checkoutdate_Month_ID").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

$("#checkoutdate_Day_ID").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

$("#checkoutdate_Year_ID").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

$("#room_type").change(function() {

change_charges();

});

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  Your problem is described as "rather than giving 2 days at 1 price and then say 1 day for another price it doesnt".  Should it always give 2 days at one price, then one at another?  What is it doing now instead?  It's not at all obvious to me what is intended here.

Comment: 1) 28/10 - 31/10 = 3 nights stay -  should be 3 x 1995 = 5985 

System Calculation - 7985

Comment: This is one example whereby it is not calculating the price as it should for these dates - rather than 3 days @ 1995

Comment: It should basically give the user a price at whatever dates they choose - and if the prices fall across a date range then it should give 1 price which combines prices from either side of date range to give correct total if that makes sense ?!?! :)

Comment: 2) 29/10 - 2/11 = 4 days - should be 3 x 1995 & 1 x 2995 - 8980

System Calculation - 9980 - this another example

Comment: Please don't try to make people decipher your calculation algorithim. Just ask a direct question

Comment: i am trying to ask a direct question - basically the way the code is above it does not calculate properly across a date range - if for example 3 days (date range 1) and 3 days (date range 2) it gives 6 days at date range 1

Comment: I don't see where, in the code, you actually compute the total... I see only mon_stay, which is a number of days, but not the charge computation. What's the formula ? (I don't understand the charges and n_charges difference either)

Comment: try closing your main function - i can't see where you close the anonymus function

Comment: i have added the code which calculates now - i have only added snippets thats why i think is not closed

Answer (score 1):

you computation function is wrong :
taking your first example : 3 days @ 1995 =5985
what you code is the following :
stay=3
mon_stay=1 (because you wrote : if mon_stay =0 then mon_stay=1)
then

charges = 1*1995 + 2* 2995
= 7985 !

a better formula would be (I think but it's difficult to understand)

```
charges = (mon_stay*n_charges) + (rem_stay*charges);
```

without the mon_stay=1 (unless it is intended)

Comment: so do u mean without mon_stay = 1; it would calculate as 3 x 1995 = 5985 ?

Comment: without that it gets 2 right but not this 4) 14/12 - 17/12 = 3 days - should be 2 x 2995 & 1 x 5990 - 11980

Comment: actually, the full approach seems very strange, because that would fail if your stay period encompasses more than 2 periods. You may rather just cut you period en days, than go through your list of day and sum the charge for that particular day.